# Store Data (Posts) fetched from Wordpress to Android app via JSON to view offline

Tags: android, json, wordpress, android-activity, android-fragments

This is my first post.

I have an application which is **fetching** data from a **wordpress site**. The wordpress site is actually a news site & the application actually uses the **JSON** to connect with the Wordpress site via plugin.

The main problem is, when there is no internet connection, the application prompts: "No internet connection available!" as coded in the activity, but I want to do the following thing:

- If internet is **connected**, then fetch data from the site as usual
- If there is **no internet connection**, show the **previous data**

Problem actually arises where the save data has to take place. As of my research, there are three methods:

1. Shared Preferences
2. SQL-Lite Database
3. File Handling

I want to know which would be **best**? & any **source code** will be highly appreciated.
And if the data is to be saved, how to **view the data** when there is **no internet connection available**?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have only one (or just a few) JSON file you could actually save it to a file. It should work pretty much like this:
If i have internet connection, i download the json from the server, and i save it to a file and display data. If i dont have it i check if the file exists (it will only be missing if its the first time the user started using the app), and if it does, i read the file, and display json data. You can achieve this with a simple txt file. 
Here's some sample code that will help you start:

1. writing string to a file

   public void writeFile(String data) {
           String filename = "myfile.json";
           FileOutputStream outputStream = null;

   ```
       try {
           outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           outputStream.write(data.getBytes());
           outputStream.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

   }
   ```

   reading from file:

   public String readJsonFromFile() {
               String json = null;

   ```
           try {

               InputStream is = openFileInput("myfile.json");

               int size = is.available();

               byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

               is.read(buffer);

               is.close();

               json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

           } catch (IOException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
               return null;
           }
           return json;

       }
   ```

and JSONObject to a string

```
JSONObject json;
String s;
s=json.toString();
```

The other way around: string to json

```
String s;
JSONObject json= new JSONObject(s);
```